# How to use materialize-css with angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, materialize

I have created an **angular4** project with **angular-cli**. I want to [materialize-css@next](http://next.materializecss.com/) library. So I have installed it using

```
npm install materialize-css@next --save
```

so this installed

```
"materialize-css": "^1.0.0-alpha.2",
```

Then in the angular-cli.json I have added reference to css and js file

```
"styles": [
   "styles.css",
   "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"
],
"scripts": [
   "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
],
```

Now this is working fine for normal components like button and navigation bar as these components do not need any js.

How can I create dynamic elements like the carousel, collapsible and other components in which there is the requirement for js?

As I have googled there are wrapper libraries like **angualr2-materialize**

So I have installed this

```
npm install angular2-materialize --save
```

And imported the module in my **app.module.ts**

```
import { MaterializeModule } from 'angular2-materialize';
```

and then in `imports` array of `@NgModule`

```
imports: [
  BrowserModule,
  MaterializeModule
],
```

and when I use the following markup

```
<a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" (click)="openModal()">Modal</a>

<div id="modal1" class="modal bottom-sheet" materialize="modal" [materializeParams]="[{dismissible: false}]" [materializeActions]="modalActions">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Modal Header</h4>
        <p>A bunch of text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a class="waves-effect waves-green btn-flat" (click)="closeModal()">Close</a>
        <a class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is showing

```
index.js:4 Uncaught Error: Couldn't find Materialize object on window. It is created by the materialize-css library. Please import materialize-css before importing angular2-materialize.
    at Object.../../../../angular2-materialize/dist/index.js (index.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f20633ecefcae2ee4f21:54)
    at Object.../../../../../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f20633ecefcae2ee4f21:54)
    at Object.../../../../../src/main.ts (environment.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f20633ecefcae2ee4f21:54)
    at Object.3 (main.ts:11)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap f20633ecefcae2ee4f21:54)
    at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap f20633ecefcae2ee4f21:25)
    at main.bundle.js:1
```

Am I missing something?

Is there any way to use MaterializeCSS library without using wrappers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`angular2-materialize` is based on `materialize-css 0.X`. As `materialize-css 1.X` has not dependency on `jQuery`. Even I did not found any wrapper over this and I don't want to use the wrapper modules. So I have solved this problem by following these steps.

1) JS and CSS Reference in **angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
   "styles.css",
   "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css"
],
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.js",
  "../node_modules/materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js"
]
```

`hammerjs` is required for some components to listen sliding events.

2) Import in ts

```
import * as M from "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize";
```

3) Get the element Reference

```
@ViewChild('collapsible') elCollapsible: ElementRef;
```

4) Wrap the element

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let instanceCollapsible = new M.Collapsible(this.elCollapsible.nativeElement, {});
}
```

5) Do not forget `#collapsible` on your `<ul #collapsible>`

And done.

Comment: i am stucked at the step 2, 3 and 4
Please guide me how to implement materialize.css.

Comment: To suppress the error in the console please add {read: ElementRef}
@ViewChild('collapsible', { read: ElementRef }) elCollapsible: ElementRef;

Comment: And for using @ViewChilderen Step 4
elems['_results'].forEach(el => console.log(el.nativeElement))

Comment: @AbdulRehmanKhan make sure to find the location of your node_modules

Comment: Please add a Step 5) do not forget  #collapsible on your <ul  #collapsible>

Comment: to solve the ['_results'] use QueryList<ElementRef>; This is from angular core

Answer (score 2):

1) Install Materialize:

```
yarn add material-design-icons-iconfont
yarn add materialize-css
yarn add -D @types/materialize-css
```

2) Import Materialize styles:

```
@import '~material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css';
@import '~materialize-css/sass/materialize';
```

3) Create HTML for the component:

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="#!" (click)="logout()">Logout</a></li>
  </ul>
  <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Akita</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a routerLink="dashboard" *showIfLoggedIn="true">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li><a routerLink="todos" *showIfLoggedIn="true">Todos</a></li>
        <li *showIfLogin="false"><a *showIfLoggedIn="false" routerLink="login"
            class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Login</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown" #dropdown>Welcome, {{ name$ | async}}!<i
              class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

4) Import Materialize and bind the dropdown:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as M from 'materialize-css';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthQuery, AuthService } from '../auth/state';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-main-nav',
  templateUrl: './main-nav.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-nav.component.scss']
})
export class MainNavComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  name$: Observable<string>;

  @ViewChild('dropdown') dropdown: ElementRef;

  constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private authQuery: AuthQuery) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name$ = this.authQuery.name$;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    new M.Dropdown(this.dropdown.nativeElement, {});
  }

  logout() {
    this.authService.logout();
    this.router.navigateByUrl('');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

angular2-materialize probably uses Materialize 0.x which uses the `Materialize` namespace. materialize-next switchted to the `M` namespace.

angular2-materialize should already include Materialize (0.x).

Comment: Then i need to switch to 0.x? What if I want to use the 1.X?

Comment: is there any way I can use it without wrapper libraries?

Comment: Sure, but then you can not use the wrapper libraries if they do not yet support 1.x.

Comment: In this case I suggest asking at the wrapper libraries' repositories if there is support for Materialize 1.x or if there are workarounds to mix the old Materialize version with the new version.

Comment: If I want to use it directely without using any wrapper class?

Comment: That should be always possible with Angular and ng attributes.