# new Materialize CSS with Angular how to impl?

Tags: angular, materialize

I just want to know what is the best way to implement Materialze in Angular project 
- I found "ng2-materialize" that helps with that but for that I need to install jQuery that should not be mixed with Angular (what I understood) , the new version of Materiazlize does not need jQuery and althoug had no problem to iplement the styles I could not menage to implement js classes of Materialize and could not find any angular wrapper for it.

I found this [How to use materialize-css with angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007665/how-to-use-materialize-css-with-angular)
 but is it still the best solution  or should I stick with 'ng2-materialize'?

Comment: You can always use jQuery with AngularJS in fact AngularJS library itself contains a light version of jQuery integrated inside. It is recommended not to mix AngulrJS and jQuery code but you can import both libraries if dependency is required. It works.

Comment: ok, but would U use a "ng2-materialize" wrapper or would U use the solution used in the question I linked to..?

Comment: You can use either of the two depending on your use case. If angular2-materialize provides you all the tools that you require then go for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are building an angular application I would highly recommend you use the [ng2-materialize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-materialize) wrapper. This allows you to have a cleaner application, it simplifies the way you handle components, and it eliminates some of the problems that arise when you simply use the materialize JS and CSS.

Comment: what kind of problems can accure if I would use JS if I may ask (just wondering :))