# Mi materializecss .datepicker is not working unless make a refresh on the website

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, datepicker, materialize

I'm working for the first time with materialize in angular, the toruble i'm having is that my datepicker works good but not in the first time i call the component, i need to refresh the page and then the datepicker work. If i move to another component and then i came back, it doesn't work again and again i need to refresh my page.

I hope somebody could help. Here's my code

```
    ngOnInit(): void {

    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".datepicker");
      M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
        format: 'dd-MM-yyyy',
        setDefaultDate: false,
        defaultDate: this.formate_date,
        autoClose: true,
        minDate: new Date(1970, 1, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2019, 12, 31),
        yearRange: [1970, 2019],
        i18n: {
          months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
          monthsShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
          weekdays: ['Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'],
          weekdaysShort: ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab', 'Dom'],
          weekdaysAbbrev: ['L', 'M', 'X', 'J', 'V', 'S', 'D'],
          cancel: '',
          done: '',
        }
      });
        
    });
  }
```

I use the handleChange method to get the value selected in the datepicker

```
    handleChange(e){
    var gotDate = e.target.value;
    this.user.birth_date = gotDate;   
  }
```

My index.html

```
    <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>APP</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/icon.png">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript for materialize -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">


  <!-- Importación de FonAwesome -->
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/6d6b765696.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

  <base href="/">
</head>
```

I tried this way

```
    <body>
  
  <app-root></app-root>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
          
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".datepicker");
      M.Datepicker.init(elems, {
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
        setDefaultDate: false,
        defaultDate: new Date(1970, 1, 1),
        autoClose: true,
        minDate: new Date(1970, 1, 1),
        maxDate: new Date(2019, 12, 31),
        yearRange: [1970, 2019],
        i18n: {
          months: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
          monthsShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
          weekdays: ['Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado', 'Domingo'],
          weekdaysShort: ['Lun', 'Mar', 'Mie', 'Jue', 'Vie', 'Sab', 'Dom'],
          weekdaysAbbrev: ['L', 'M', 'X', 'J', 'V', 'S', 'D'],
          cancel: '',
          done: ''
        }
      });
        
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Almost at the end of the body, and also in the head, but it's still not working

Comment: You need to initialize as part of the render.

Comment: Hi, thanks for comment, i updated the post. hope you can help me

Comment: It doesn't look like you're doing it the Angular way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48007665/how-to-use-materialize-css-with-angular